# in vb.net an error is coming

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

in vb code-i used namespace and a class.

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing this error?

Comment: Check the answer [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/941553.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The `Inherits` attribute in the `Page` directive of the aspx page must point to a class that implements the code-behind logic. If you have used extra namespaces, you will need to supply the fully qualified type name, so that it matches:

```
Inherits="The.Full.Namespace.Path.TheClassName"
```